# creating PowerShell function to use specific port for tunnel

Tags: powershell

I am writing a function to take a port as input for tunneling as below.

```
function tunnel($x){

    ssh -N -L localhost:$x:localhost:$x user@server.com
}
```

However I am getting an error as

```
(base) PS C:\Users\abc> tunnel(8888)
Bad local forwarding specification 'localhost:8888'
```

Comment: you may want to try: `& ssh -N -L localhost:$x:localhost:$x user@server.com`. May also want to clarify (*perhaps post*) the error message to get a better understanding if its PowerShell, or the ssh throwing that error.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala updated the question with more complete error message